# How to break the DATE function into different segments in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

### The First Scenario:

#### First step, user input:

I have a worksheet which is partially formatted like a horizontal calendar. Each row contains a person's name, and in the same row for each person there are 365 cells from 1 January till 31 December. Each colleague, in his/her own row, will insert a "V" in those days, in which he/she wants to do vacations.

#### Second step, automatic calculation by Excel:

Now I want Excel to read the entire row from January till December and make a list of connected vacations.

The first connected date ranges of vacations will be inserted in the same row but in two separate columns: "From-1" to "Till-1", the second connected ranges into "From-2" to "Till-2", etc.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

#### Conditions:

I want that, if there are holidays between vacations, then excel keeps the vacation days, before and after holidays, together. Like Person 1.
Where there are working-days between vacations, I want separated ranges: Like Person 6.

#### My attempt:

Someone helped me with the following formulas:

```
=DATE(YEAR($H$1),MONTH($H$1),DAY(MATCH("V",$H4:$NI4,0)))
=DATE(YEAR($H$1),MONTH($H$1),DAY(MATCH("V",$H4:$NI4,1)))
```

Where:

- `H1` is "01.01.2017" (it is formatted as month name "January 2017" in my screenshot)
- `H4` this is the first cell of the row for Person-1 to insert "V" as vacation
- `NI4` this is the last cell of the row for Person-1 to insert "V" as vacation

#### The Problem:

The above formula can make the list of ranges, just one range in a month. It means that, if a person does two different periods of vacations in one month, only the first period will be listed.

For example, if some does the first vacation from 02.01.2017 till 05.01.2017 and the second one from 10.01.2017 till 12.01.2017, then excel will calculate only the first range.
My desire is an automatic insertion of dates like Person-6 (in the screenshot I did it manually).

### The Second Scenario:

If I change the cells, in which the persons will insert V, to date format and ask them to change the color of their vacation days, will simplify the problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show that you've put some effort into resolving the issue yourself before anyone will provide code here; please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you paste the question up "inline" please? Links tend to break and will render this question useless for future readers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comments. I have already updated the question.

Comment: one of the problems you may run into is your holiday dates.  I do not believe excel has a list of holiday dates built in as they vary from country to country.  You many have to generate a custom list of holiday dates. might also want to show an example of what you want to happen when there is a holiday mixed in with the vacation dates.

Comment: couple of problems with your formulas.  1)  your ranges in your match portion need to be in the of the same row, not multiple rows.  so for person 1 they should be $H$4:$NI$4. this will cover 366 days. Just in case its a leap year.  2)  The way its setup currently it will always be January,  because you are always taking the month from $H$1. 3) What the formulas are actually telling you are the first time if finds V in a row and the last time it finds V in a row.  It ignores spaces

Comment: what are the contents of cells H2, and H3?  Is indicating vacation days allowed to be changed to V1 for first block and V2 for second block or is V only allowed to be used?  Is VBA allowed to be used or is this formula only?

Comment: Is there maximum number of days to a holiday block range?  is there a minimum?

Comment: Alternative option maybe.  Have the user enter the start and end date in the appropriate cells of the yellow and green section, and then display V in the cells in between those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I still assume that it will be better if using an udf, I still want to show a working formula... In B4:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+0,$AA$3:$CG$3+0,$E$10:$E$17)*($AA$4:$CG$4="v"),IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-1,$AA$3:$CG$3-1,$E$10:$E$17)*($Z$4:$CF$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-1,$AA$3:$CG$3-1,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-2,$AA$3:$CG$3-2,$E$10:$E$17)*($Y$4:$CE$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3-1,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-2,$AA$3:$CG$3-2,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-3,$AA$3:$CG$3-3,$E$10:$E$17)*($X$4:$CD$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3-2,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-3,$AA$3:$CG$3-3,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-4,$AA$3:$CG$3-4,$E$10:$E$17)*($W$4:$CC$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3-3,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-4,$AA$3:$CG$3-4,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3-5,$AA$3:$CG$3-5,$E$10:$E$17)*($V$4:$CB$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3-4)))))))))),FLOOR(COLUMN(),3)/3+1),"")}
```

assumptions:

- your calendar starts at column AA
- column V to Z are empty
- dates for holidays are from E10 to E17
- only a max of 4 days in a row can be not-working-days (does not matter for the length of the vacation itself)
- calendar goes till column CG (should be February 28th) and needs to be extended

This array formula can simply be pasted to other rows and columns E, H, ...
Still I suggest for E4 to wrap it in an `=IF(B4="","",.......)` to cut calculation time.

For C4 (end date) you can use this formula which is just a bit different:

```
{=IF(B4="","",SMALL(IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+0,$AA$3:$CG$3+0,$E$10:$E$17)*($AA$4:$CG$4="v"),IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+1,$AA$3:$CG$3+1,$E$10:$E$17)*($AB$4:$CH$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+1,$AA$3:$CG$3+1,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+2,$AA$3:$CG$3+2,$E$10:$E$17)*($AC$4:$CI$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3+1,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+2,$AA$3:$CG$3+2,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+3,$AA$3:$CG$3+3,$E$10:$E$17)*($AD$4:$CJ$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3+2,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+3,$AA$3:$CG$3+3,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+4,$AA$3:$CG$3+4,$E$10:$E$17)*($AE$4:$CK$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3+3,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+4,$AA$3:$CG$3+4,$E$10:$E$17)=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS($AA$3:$CG$3+5,$AA$3:$CG$3+5,$E$10:$E$17)*($AF$4:$CL$4<>"v"),$AA$3:$CG$3+4)))))))))),FLOOR(COLUMN(),3)/3))}
```

This formula can freely be copied anywhere directly right from the other formula.

But as said: that is not the way I would go... still it shows, how to do without any helper cells/rows/columns and/or vba. I will look for a fast vba solution but that may take some time ;)

**EDIT 3**

After reading all the comments again, I probably got you wrong. This way I'll add a shortened code which starts and ends at the first and last real vacation day. (Edit 1 and 2 deleted due to the fact that I've misread what you want)

```
Option Explicit

Dim vacArr As Variant

Public Function getVacArr(ByVal FirstDay As Long, ByVal LastDay As Long, Optional ByVal Holidays As Variant) As Long
  If IsMissing(Holidays) Then Holidays = 0
  vacArr = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("Row(" & FirstDay & ":" & LastDay & ")"))
  vacArr = Application.NetworkDays(vacArr, vacArr, Holidays)
  getVacArr = FirstDay
End Function

Public Function vacDays(ByVal initVal As Long, ByVal VRng As Range, Optional ByVal Cnt As Long = 1) As Variant

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, VRngVal As Variant, InH As Boolean

  If Not (IsArray(vacArr) And initVal > 0 And Cnt > 0) Then vacDays = Split("  ", " "): Exit Function

  VRngVal = VRng.Resize(1).Value
  k = Application.Min(UBound(vacArr), VRng.Columns.Count)

  For i = 1 To k

    While vacArr(i) = 0 And i < k: i = i + 1: Wend
    If vacArr(i) = 0 Then Exit For

    If InH <> (VRngVal(1, i) = "V") Then
      InH = Not InH
      Cnt = Cnt + InH
      If Cnt = 0 And InH Then vacDays = initVal + i - 1
    End If

    If Cnt = 0 And VRngVal(1, i) = "V" Then j = initVal + i - 1: l = l + 1

    If Not CBool(Cnt Or InH) Then Exit For

  Next

  If IsEmpty(vacDays) Then
    vacDays = Split("  ", " ")
  Else
    vacDays = Array(vacDays, j, l)
  End If

End Function
```

[image]

- B4:D4 uses the first udf as: `{=vacDays($AA$3,$AA4:$OA4,RIGHT(B$3))}` which can be copied (all three cells) to all other locations where you need it

  - the `RIGHT(B$3)` is just to get 1, 2, 3... for the kth match
- AA1 has the direct date for the first January of the year 2017

  - All merged rages to the right are formated manually (ok, I used a sub to do it but that doesn't matter)
- AA2 has: `=AA3` and is copied to the right
- AA3 holds the helper udf as: `=getVacArr(AA1,OA3,$E$11:$E$20)` (non array)
- AB3 is: `=AA1+1` (to avoid circular referencing)
- AC3 is: `=AB3+1` and also be copied to the right
- AA2:OA3 hold the real dates (this may slow down excel if the initial value is volatile like `TODAY`, so I suggest having the first date directly typed in and then just `+1` each cell from another)
  As always: if you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you so much for your extensive and detailed answer. Sorry for my delay, because I was in Urlaub :). I am following your instruction, but I have a question: when I insert the formula in the OA3 as the last day of year, the excel warns me because of "Circular reference" and it refers to AA3 as the start point of this circulation. I am blocked at this point, would you help me please how can I solve that. I uploaded my file, if by any chance you find some time to take a look at it, will be a great help. [https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3230806/Vacation%20Calculator.xlsm]

Comment: OK, I've checked it, and there was an error in my explanation... I've shortened and changed my code a bit and simply missed it. I corrected your file which you can download [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_752Ga6Yb7uaDZzYW5ZaWUxdDQ). If you still have any trouble, just ask :)

Comment: @Dio I almost forgot: if the vacation-range is empty, then "reenter" the the helper cell. (simply double click the cell and then enter) ;)

Comment: YES... It works, thank you so much Dirk for your help and time. Viele Grüße. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Download XLCalendar.xlsx](http://icwebstudios.net/public_html/gaming/uploads/XLCalendar.xlsx)
It would be much easier you have you Employees put in the start date and end date of the two vacation periods.
The spreadsheets would then display a **V** for each workday in the vacation period.

> IF(AND(OR(AND(H$2>=$B4,H$2<=$C4),AND(H$2>=$E4,H$2<=$F4)),WEEKDAY(H$2,2)<6),"V","")

The NETWORKDAYS function will easily return the actually number of vacation days taken.

> =NETWORKDAYS(B4,C4,HolidayListRange)

Advantages:

- The End User doesn't have to scroll through this huge spreadsheet
- User Input will be limited to 4 columns.  Making it much easier to debug and password protect your formula

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply and sorry for my delay, I was in vacation. Your idea and reason is correct, but regarding my personal experience, working with graphical calendar view is easier. I may spend a long time to complete this calendar, but the result will ease the work of many employees. While I am working on the VBA solution, I am also thinking seriously about yours. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can flag the second block of vacation as a different character or set of characters such as V1 and V2 or V and X the following changes should work for you.

In cell B4 use:

```
=$H$1+MATCH("V1",$H4:$NI4,0)-1
```

In cell C4 use:

```
=WORKDAY(B4,D4-1)
```

In cell D4 use

```
=COUNTIF($H4:$NI4,"v1")
```

Repeat the same formulas in your E to F columns updating the address to point in the right spot and change the V1 to V2 or whatever distinct identifier you choose.

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, I reply all your comments here:  About holidays: I have a list of holidays. It will be calculated in the (D) and (G) column, where I calculate the NETWORKDAYs.  Your numbered comments: 1) Yes, I have all ranges of each person in the same row, 2) I noticed the error and I corrected. But the problem still remains, 3)I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. The formula doesn't differentiate between "V"s. The difference between "V"s is the the date at the top of the column.

Comment: Forward ED, I prefer to not differentiate between set of characters. There are numerous colleagues and if some of them make mistake, it will be problematic. The goal of this table is to simplify their work. Howerver thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Without being able to distinguish between the identifier, I am not sure how with excel formulas to identify the end f the first range and the start of the second range.  This could be done quite easily with VBA but I did not see a VBA tag in your question and assumed this was not an option.

Comment: with 3 I was stating that your formula only identify the date of the first V and the last V.  Your description of what the formulas did in your original question was slightly off.  Put a second vacation block for person 1 in say December and watch what happens to your end date for range 1

Comment: About the (3), you are right. I tried it. About VBA, if there is an easy way to do it, I will appreciate any help. I add the VBA tag to my question. By the way, what do you think about the "Second Scenario" which I added yesterday? With so thanks, Omid

Comment: Dealing with colour is not possible with formulas as far as I know.  VBA on the other hand can deal with it no problem.  However if you are into VBA then you don't need to worry about colour as the VBA can deal with just "V".

Comment: I have a way of doing this, working the kinks out of it right now.  Its definitely not a straight forward answer.  And for the time being their maybe some restrictions.   Is there a maximum or minimum number of days each vacation block can be?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, there is no restriction for the number of vacation days. As 1st example, one person may go to vacation 20 days in one block. As 2nd example, which is my challenge to deal with formula, one person may go to vacation in 3 different and separated periods in a month. And finally as 3rd example, one person may go to vacation from last week of one month till the second week of next month, which I want to have it as one block. Sorry if it seems an order, I really appreciate your help even if it is not a forward answer.

Comment: I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Following function may lead you to the right direction.

```
Function DetermineVacations(RangeDates As Range, RangeDays As Range, RangeTextVacation As Range, PeriodEvaluated As Long)
Dim ItemDates As Range
Dim ItemDays As Range
Dim ItemText As Range
Dim RangeFoundVacations As Range
Dim FoundVacationPeriod As Range
Dim xPrevious As Long
Dim AddressCell As String
Dim SecondCellRange As String
Dim TotalVacations As Long
Dim CounterVacations As Long
Const TextVacation = "V"
If RangeTextVacation.Find("V", LookAt:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then DetermineVacations = "N/A": Exit Function
Set RangeFoundVacations = RangeTextVacation
On Error GoTo Err01DetermineVacations
AddressCell = Right(RangeFoundVacations.Address(False, False), InStr(RangeFoundVacations.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
TotalVacations = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RangeTextVacation, TextVacation)
For CounterVacations = 1 To TotalVacations
'find next doesn't work on functions, re set the range
Set FoundVacationPeriod = RangeFoundVacations.Find("V", LookAt:=xlPart)
'here you need to relate PeriodEvaluated vs the searc being performed
Set RangeFoundVacations = Range(FoundVacationPeriod.Address(False, False) & ":" & AddressCell)

Next CounterVacations
If 1 = 2 Then '99. If error
Err01DetermineVacations:
DetermineVacations = "N/A"
End If '99. If error
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I have knocked this up which works as long as there are 2 vacations on there.

I will try to perfect it tomorrow, but I must go home now.

To start off I added the Weekends as W using the below script:

```
Sub Weekend()
Dim X, Y As Integer
Dim mydate As Range

For Y = 4 To 9
For X = 8 To 372

Set mydate = Cells(3, X)

        If Weekday(mydate, vbMonday) > 5 Then
            Sheets("Urlaub (2017)").Cells(Y, X).Value = "W"
        End If

Next X
Next Y


End Sub
```

Then using the below code I got the other fields completed. As mentioned I will edit tomorrow after sorting out a few things.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Y, Col As Integer
Dim VStart1, VEnd1, V1 As Range
Dim VStart2, VEnd2, V2 As Range
Dim Days1, Days2 As Long

For Y = 4 To 9
On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("Urlaub (2017)")
    'Find first V
    Set VStart1 = .Rows(Y).Find("V", Cells(Y, 8), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not VStart1 Is Nothing Then
        'Jump to the end of that block
        Col = VStart1.End(xlToRight).Column
            'If ends on a weekend then strip off 2 days
            If .Cells(Y, Col).Value = "W" Then
            Col = Col - 2
            End If
        Set VEnd1 = Cells(Y, Col)
        'Set the full vacation range
        Set V1 = .Range(VStart1.Address & ":" & VEnd1.Address)
        End If

    Set VStart2 = .Rows(Y).Find("V", VEnd1, xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not VStart2 Is Nothing Then
        Col = VStart2.End(xlToRight).Column
            If .Cells(Y, Col).Value = "W" Then
            Col = Col - 2
            End If
        Set VEnd2 = Cells(Y, Col)

        Set V2 = .Range(VStart2.Address & ":" & VEnd2.Address)
        End If


'Now you have the 2 vacations as V1 and V2 (this could be repeated again if you wanted to expand)

Range("B" & Y).Value = Cells(3, VStart1.Column)
Range("C" & Y).Value = Cells(3, VEnd1.Column)
Range("D" & Y).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(V1, "V")
Range("E" & Y).Value = Cells(3, VStart2.Column)
Range("F" & Y).Value = Cells(3, VEnd2.Column)
Range("G" & Y).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(V2, "V")

    End With
Next Y

End Sub
```

It's not perfect but it's a start and gives you something to work on. a bit of nip and tuck and this'll be there

Answer (score 0):

Take care to note that in order to use this function the way it is written, you will need to implement the following change:

In row 3, from columns H to NI, you need to change from the number `1` to the date `01.01.17` formatted as `"dd"`. You can achieve this easily by entering `01.01.17` in the left-most cell, then clicking and dragging the little square in the lower right of the selection box. Once all the cells are filled, simply right-click and apply the custom formatting.

Furthermore, you need to update this line with whatever color you're using:

`If C.Interior.color <> 6013439`

To find the color of the cell, select that cell, switch to the VBA Editor, open the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G), and enter `? Selection.Interior.Color`. The resulting number will be what you need to input in the above line of code (unless the background has no fill (and take care to note that "white" and "no fill" is not the same!), in which case it's `xlNone`).

```
Function VacationRangeCalculator(rng As String, v As Integer, Cycle As Integer) As String
    ' rng = set to A-column, whatever row you want to evaluate, v = 1 or 2, depending on whether you want the start or the end of a range _
    ' Cycle = 1 or 2, depending on whether you want the 1st or 2nd vacation range

    Dim r As Long ' Row
    Dim streak As Boolean
    Dim streakNum As Integer

    r = Range(rng).Row

    For Each C In Range("H" & r, "NI" & r)
        If LCase(C.Value) = "v" Then ' If this day is a vacation day
            If streak = False Then ' If we're not on a streak
                streak = True ' Start streak
                streakNum = streakNum + 1 ' Increment streak counter
            End If
            If v = 1 And streakNum = Cycle Then ' The first range of the given cycle
                VacationRangeCalculator = Cells(3, C.Column).Value ' Return result
                Exit For ' Terminate calculation
            End If
        Else ' This is not a vacation day
            If C.Interior.color <> 6013439 Then ' If this day is not a weekend
                streak = False ' End streak
                If v = 2 And streakNum = Cycle Then ' The second range of the given cycle
                    VacationRangeCalculator = Cells(3, C.Column - 1).Value ' Return result
                    Exit For ' Terminate calculation
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Sub vacations()
    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A4", 1, 1)
    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A4", 2, 1)

    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A4", 1, 2)
    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A4", 2, 2)

    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A5", 1, 1)
    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A5", 2, 1)

    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A5", 1, 2)
    Debug.Print VacationRangeCalculator("A5", 2, 2)
End Sub
```

Producing the following results:

```
03.01.2016
10.01.2016


03.01.2016
04.01.2016
10.01.2016
11.01.2016
```

when my worksheet looks like this:

[image]

For the case illustrated by your screenshot, input the following:

In B4: `=VacationRangeCalculator(B4, 1, 1)`
In C4: `=VacationRangeCalculator(B4, 2, 1)`
In E4: `=VacationRangeCalculator(B4, 1, 2)`
In F4: `=VacationRangeCalculator(B4, 2, 2)`

Which will give you something looking like this:

[image]

The formula only has to be entered 4 times, once for each column. After that, you can select the entire range and drag it down (using the same method as described at the start of the post, just done vertically instead of horizontally).

It's also possible to modify the UDF so that it is self-referencing the cell it is being called in (but this also means further checks/hacks are required if you want to call it from VBA) - I will leave that as an exercise to the reader, but will give the hint that it involves using `Application.Caller`.

Comment: If recalculations become time-consuming, it might be better to rewrite this as a `Sub` instead of `Function`. Which is easy to do. Or you might just encapsulate it in a `Sub` using a loop and 4 `Evaluate` calls.